# Gurobi: Constraint formulation - Ratios decision variables

Tags: python, gurobi

Currently I am working with gurobipy and would like to model the following constraint (X1 to X4 are decision variables):

```
a * X1 = b * X2 = c * X3 = a * X4
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be converted to standard form for linear programming. I recommend that you introduce a new unconstrained variable z, meaning that the lower bound (LB attribute) is -GRB.INFINITY. Then write:

```
a * X1 == z
b * X2 == z
c * X3 == z
a * X4 == z
```

I realize that you could eliminate z (and presolve should do this), but the reason why you add the variable z is for other applications where the terms are linear expressions instead of single variables; in that case, the form I suggested will be more efficient.

Comment: That's fantastic, never stop learning and this actually solves me quite a bit of trouble.